# Issue on Redirect URI in DotNet MVC Web App during Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

I Have Created Dotnet MVC Web APP which is going to use Azure AD with OpenID , i am facing while iam trying signin an user

The Sign in Operation works By first asking the user's Consent and getting the Token from Azure AD which redirected Back to the Application.During The Redirection process how should i declare the redirect uri, since i have used OpenIdConnect is it mandatory to mention signin/oidc followed by application Uri

Error
AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application

I Have Followed same process in Azure AD Samples as Mentioned

Comment: The problem is with your redirectUrl .Please debug and check the value coming in redirectUrl

Comment: @HariKrishna--MSFTIdentity The Value is coming as https://localhost:44330/signin-oidc in Azure Portal while creating redirect uri have not mentioned signin-odic

Comment: You must ensure that the redirect_uri configured in the Azure portal is exactly the same as the redirect_uri configured in the code.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must ensure that the redirect_uri configured in the Azure portal is exactly the same as the redirect_uri configured in the project's configuration file.

For your question, if the redirect_uri set in Azure Portal is `https://localhost:44330/signin-oidc`, then it should also be `https://localhost:44330/signin-oidc` in the configuration file.

Please see: [Configuration files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-app-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore#configuration-files).

Comment: I was missing signin-oidc int the Azure Portal. Thank you